# Nginx - Separate location for /

Tags: nginx

I'd like to use nginx to have one location used for just the root url (https://example.com/) and serve all other file from a different location.
Eventually I want to use this to do authentication on / before proxying, but initially I'm just trying with simple file locations.

Based on the documentation I'm using two location blocks:

```
server {
  listen  443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/cert.key;

  location = / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
  }

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html2;
  }
}
```

But requests for https:// example.com/ are getting /usr/share/nginx/html2/index.html rather than /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html

Similarly, I've tried:

```
  location = / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
  }

  location ~* ^/.* {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html2;
  }
```

But I get the same result.

Is there a straightforward way to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the index directive will make an internal redirect to `/index.html` thus it's matching the second location block. Change the first block to this :

```
location ~ ^/(index\.html)?$ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
}
```